# Are inherited member variables' values passed back to parent class from child class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, pass-by-reference, multiple-inheritance

I've been trying to test a bunch of different code to see if this works. I started testing a bunch of simple things, but I ended up resorting to more verbose methods when I saw those didn't work. I believe it will work if I pass the instance of the parent class to the child class, but that can get really messy after first-level inheritance and I'd definitely prefer to not have to take that route if there are other more efficient alternatives.

What I have is a function and a variable in the class `MainParent` that get inherited by the `FirstChild` and `SecondChild` classes. Normally, if the variable were to be referenced in the `FirstChild` or `SecondChild` class, the variable data for both classes would be independent of each other.

However, what I need it to do is when `FirstChild` updates the variable created in the `MainParent` class, the changes made by `FirstChild` should also be implemented to the variable's data inside the `SecondChild` class.

Like I said, I can easily get it to work if I pass along a variable or instance of the parent class to each child class, but I'd like this happen without any parameter passing, because that can get messy after a few levels of inheritance.

I can show the code that I've been working on, but I really don't think that it's relevant because I'm pretty sure that's just not in the design of PHP's OOP (or any OOP that I know of).

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Also, what about using reference variables? I thought about calling an outside function which accepted a reference variable and to just do it that way, but it's not a very elegant solution and frankly isn't any simpler than passing an instance of the parent to the child manually.

I don't think this is going to be as clean and tidy as I had wanted, but I'm really hoping someone will step in and prove me wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about static variables? i.e. Make the variable that you want to share across objects static in the parent class.

Comment: correct, do write some test cases

Comment: I don't think that would solve the problem of having to pass something back and forth though, because if I create a new instance of FirstChild and a new instance of SecondChild, they won't share the same instance of MainParent, so the data can't be relayed unless manually passed. Is this correct?

Comment: @danL: incorrect. a static property is static. Once changed all classes based on the class where the property is defined "see the update". I have a feeling though that static properties are probably not going to be what you need here. I suspect youre going to have to end up using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in some manner instead, but without code samples for some context i cant say.

Comment: Okay I will play around with it. I will update my question and let you know if I don't figure out how to do what you're suggesting. Thank you.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do and why, but: don't think in terms of classes, think in terms of objects. OOP is all about objects and classes are merely blueprints for their creation. Once created, your objects shouldn't care about the inheritance hierarchy and they definitely can't "modify parent class". Or any class, for that matter.